# React life cycle in Safari using back button

Tags: reactjs, safari, react-router, mobile-safari

Got an issue with safari loading a react app when back button is clicked. I have tried "pageshow" event but persisted event.persisted is always false and it seems that the lifecycle of react is not being execute.

Do you know if there is a way to force the lifecycle in react when the back button is clicked in safari?

Thanks in advance for your answers, also me know if you have questions.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this.  I am in a similar situation

Comment: I find a solution, not the cleanest. I am using pageshow and popstate events and setting an state when those events are triggered in that way the component render again. hope that help in some way.